# How to play video on whole browser tab

Tags: browser, browser-addons

How to fill a browser tab with video from YouTube or other video hosting sites,instead of filling the whole screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Chrome, the following add-on will enable you to maximize flash videos in it's tab:

[Maximize Flash](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/maximize-flash/chihjmmmhbapnhemoopibkekbojilhge?hl=en)

> Make a flash video use as much screen size as the tab it's in and the aspect ratio allows, without causing the video to reload.

Comment: Please see the [guidelines on recommending software](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers). A link isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the embedded mode, normally used to embed YouTube links in web pages.

The easiest way is to replace some text in the URL, specifically replace 'watch?v=' with 'embed/'. This will load the embedded version, using the full tab. Something like:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bfar69ZVnlU

to

https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bfar69ZVnlU

You can also go to Sharing, Embed and copy the URL inside the 'src="XXXXXXXXXX"' element of the offered HTML source.

As far as I know, this will work in every browser.

Comment: When I try this, it gives the following message: `An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback ID: cZaqryWMgTju_KgU)`